# Model to use in Cassandra to store repeated data

Tags: cassandra, cql

Im trying to store a list of values where the data is very similar. 
I need to create a table model where upserts are avoided and the queries can be made by using (date,hour and country).

```
hour;date;country;unit;type;energy;price;offer;

1;01/01/2016;MI;C;3,6;180,30;O;
1;01/01/2016;MI;C;20,0;180,30;O;
1;01/01/2016;MI;C;837,3;180,30;O;
1;01/01/2016;MI;C;3,4;180,30;O
1;01/01/2016;MI;C;0,6;180,30;O;
1;01/01/2016;MI;C;0,8;180,30;O;
1;01/01/2016;MI;C;1,5;180,30;O;
1;16/12/2016;ES;V;1,5;0;C;
1;16/12/2016;ES;V;0,4;0;C;
```

I studied user defined types (UDT) a little. Is this a good example to implement them?

For instance it's possible to apply a compound partition key to (hour, date and country) and a field `readings` to a data type composed by "`unidad,tipo oferta,energía,precio,ofertada`"?

Is this the best approach to keep and search for data ?

Answer (score 2):

From what I can understand, your problem is related to multiple `hour:date:country` tuples that must co-exist.

I would first "collapse" hour and date to one `timestamp` field only (optional), and then add a "random" `timeuuid` field as clustering key. This would allow to have a set of rows belonging to the same tuple `time stamp:country`.

The table would look like

```
CREATE TABLE mutable (
    country text,
    ts timestamp,
    ck timeuuid,
    ....
    PRIMARY KEY ((country, ts), ck)
)
```

Comment: That sounds good, i will test your solution. The timeuuid type offers uniqueness everytime is generated right? Thank you!

Comment: It supports up to 10k uuid per ms IIRC. Please have a look at docs to be sure its a good fit. You'll need your "random" implementation otherwise (e.g. application counter).

Answer (score 0):

This seems a good case to use Time series in Cassandra, as you have a scalar value that is dependent of the time
https://academy.datastax.com/resources/getting-started-time-series-data-modeling

Comment: The issue is defining the primary key.  As you can see by inspecting the data there are repeated values in possible key fields.